# Exit hook for org-src-mode

Tags: org-babel

`org-src-mode-hook` is run upon editing a source block using `org-edit-src-mode`. Is there a way to set behaviour upon exiting editing a source block?

In particular I would like to run `blacken-buffer` upon exiting editing a block of Python code.

Comment: the docstring of `org-src-mode-hook` says it is run "after entering **or leaving** `org-src-mode`".

Comment: @JeanPierre That's right. However, exiting editing a source block doesn't trigger leaving `org-src-mode`, the buffer simply gets killed, the `org-src-mode` buffer-local minor mode won't be disabled.

Comment: @xuchunyang Oh indeed, very good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to advice the `org-edit-src-exit` command, for example,

```el
(define-advice org-edit-src-exit (:before (&rest _args) format-python)
  "Run `blacken-buffer' on Python code."
  (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (message "Formatting python code...")
    (blacken-buffer)))
```

I don't have the `blacken-buffer` command available, thus I don't know if the above actually works.